# How do I create a random string generator in Google Sheets with assigned probabilities for each string and no replacement within the generator?

Tags: google-sheets, random, spreadsheet, probability

I am creating an "application" and within the application I am creating a random pitching repertoire for pitchers. Right now, I have the generator just picking a random number of strings between 3-5 and without replacement; but, I would like to include the assigned probabilities of each pitch being chosen in an individual's repertoire.

The "application" is linked below.

[IFA Generator](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1umWGlMLLbHuIZ35vtBR2P8gzU7ljW0CbtsH8W1o2tl8/edit?usp=sharing)

**Note:** Because of the sharing options, you may have to download the sheet to edit it.

The range/cell I am adjusting is **M10(:M14)**. Right now, the code I have is...

*=if(F7 = "No", sortn(pitches, randbetween(3,5), randarray(len(pitches))), "NA")*

"pitches", is the range of pitch types in the range below.

Although this works well, I would like to adjust it to include the assigned probabilities for each pitch. Those probabilities can be found on the "Misc." sheet in the range **N2:Q12**.

Comment: You want to add the probability as `Changeup - 0.10` in the same cell or will you be willing to add a cell next to it with the probability? Or use a helper table?

Comment: I would be willing to have a helper cell with the probability associated with each pitch type.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new table with 6 rows and 3 columns (in the range K31:M36), like this:

[image: New table]

*Note: You can use it as a helper table, change the color to white  so it is not visible.*

And added the formula:

```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      F7="No",VLOOKUP(
        sortn(
          pitches, randbetween(3,5), randarray(len(pitches))
        ),
        Misc.!O3:P12,{1,2},FALSE
      ),
      {"NA","NA"}
    )
  )
```

If it works for you, you can keep it like that.

However, if you want to get the format `Changeup - 0.10` you can also add this formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    L32="NA","NA",
    IF(
      L32:L36="","",
      (L32:L36&" - "&TEXT(M32:M36, "0.00"))
      )
    )
  )
```

Inside `M10` making reference to the new helper table so it looks like this:

[image: current table]

So you will ended up with 2 tables:

[image: both tables]